# Interactive session in python paramiko module is not working in my laptop?

Tags: ssh, paramiko

```
 import base64
 import getpass
 import os
 import socket
 import sys
 import traceback
 from paramiko.py3compat import input

 import paramiko

 try:
    import interactive
 except ImportError:
    from . import interactive

 SSH_ADDRESS ="127.0.0.1"
 SSH_USERNAME ="user_name"
 SSH_PASSWORD ="password"
 SSH_PORT="22"
 client= paramiko.SSHClient()
 client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

 ssh_stdin = ssh_stdout = ssh_stderr = None  

 try: 
     client.connect(SSH_ADDRESS, 
 username=SSH_USERNAME,password=SSH_PASSWORD,port=SSH_PORT)
     chan = client.invoke_shell()`enter code here`
     interactive.interactive_shell(chan)
     chan.close()
     client.close()


 except Exception as e:
    print("*** Caught exception: %s: %s" % (e.__class__, e))
    traceback.print_exc()
    try:
        client.close()
    except:
        pass
    sys.exit(1)
```

I am using paramiko module for SSH establishment with my remote system. It actually works for one line command. But, when I used interactive session for my channel to be remain opened, it is not working. Like I didn't get output. Please help
[ssh output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XcQX.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code from your python script. Ideally, you should provide a complete standalone script which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have included my code for your reference